# php var to year and month

Tags: php, date

```
$date ='20101015';
```

how to convert to  `$year = 2010`,`$month = 10`, `$day =15`

thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php - Seriously, that's one lazy question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the PHP substring function [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) as:

```
$year  = substr($date,0,4);  # extract 4 char starting at position 0.
$month = substr($date,4,2);  # extract 2 char starting at position 4.
$day   = substr($date,6);    # extract all char starting at position 6 till end.
```

If your original string as leading or trailing spaces this would fail, so its better feed `substr` trimmed input as. So before you call `substr` you can do:

```
$date = trim($date);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in one go with

- [`sscanf`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) — Parses input from a string according to a format

Example:

```
list($y, $m, $d) = sscanf('20101015', '%4d%2d%2d');
```

or

```
sscanf('20101015', '%4d%2d%2d', $y, $m, $d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring function

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

```
$year=substr($date,0,4);
$month=substr($date,4,2);
$day=substr($date,6,2);
```